# What is the lenovo z585 highest possible specs?

Tags: upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenovo Z585 A10 8gb Ram and 1Tb hdd

I was wondering what is the highest possible specs for this laptop though sales/upgrades?

Comment: This is easily researchable, it is not well received on this site when it is clear that you haven't researched this yourself first before asking. Search the computer model you have stated and look for the highest specs in google.

Answer (score 3):

To find out what possible hardware you can put into a system, look up the "`<laptop model> specs`" in google to find the [hardware data sheet for your device](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/emea/content/pdf/IdeaPad/ZSeries/en/ideapad-z585-datasheet.pdf).

This will show you the maximum hardware capabilities of the device, though some interpretation is necessary. For example, your laptop will take 2 4GB memory chips (DDR3 SODIMM, 1600/1333Mhz). Even though they make 8GB DDR3 SODIMM memory chips, I would not expect them to work (but they might - that's a gamble); The harddrive on the other hand is listed as a 1TB drive, but it's probably just a standard 2.5" SATA connector - I would expect a 2.5" SSD to fit in there just fine, or a 2TB 2.5" HDD. Some things, like the processor and GPU, typically can't be replaced at all, and even if multiple CPU/GPU configurations are listed on the data sheet, you'll be stuck with whichever one you bought.

Googling "`<laptop model> manual`" will also typically get you the [hardware replacement manual](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_z380_z480_z485_z580_z585_hmm_1st_edition_feb_2012_english.pdf) for your system, which will tell you how to access and replace parts of the computer which are user-replaceable, and will tell you things such as if the WiFi module is connected via a Mini-PCIe connector and can be replaced or not with a new one. For example, I would expect that you can replace the 2.4 GHz Wifi B/G/N module with a more recent 2.4/5 GHz A/B/G/N/AC module (but don't take my word for it - use google to see if you can find someone that has dome something like that first, or make sure you can return the new module if it doesn't work).